# Finding Probability that data is taken from a Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: bayesian, scikit-learn, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I'm using [scikit's Gaussian Mixture](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html) to obtain a 2 component mixture model for some 1-D data. Having obtained a model, I want to test how well a different data set matches this mixture model, or more precisely, with what probability is some data taken from this mixture model. I've tried using `gmm.score()` in order to obtain the log likelihood, then exponentiating it, but this give me a number greater than 1. What's the proper way to obtain probabilities in this case?

Comment: The likelihood for a continuous distribution is a *density,* not a probability.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220.

Comment: To obtain the "probability that a dataset is from a given model", one would need to give a meaning to the contraposite, i.e. to model that the data is not from a given model...